# What is the exact HTTP content used to call a WCF web service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service, which was created using the Visual Studio 2013 *New Project* wizard.  I can call this service using the *WCF Test Client* which works fine.  However, I'd like to call the service from the command line using *curl*.

What I've done is copied the *Request* content from the WCF Test Client, which looks like:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService1/TestStr</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <TestStr xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And stuck it in a file called `Test.txt`.  Then, from the command line I did:

```
curl --verbose --header "Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8" -X POST -d @Test.txt http://localhost:64777/Service1.svc
```

What I get back is:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x50e5a0
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x50e5a0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 64777 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 64777 (#0)
> POST /Service1.svc HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.33.0
> Host: localhost:64777
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8
> Content-Length: 343
>
* upload completely sent off: 343 out of 343 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Cache-Control: private
* Server Microsoft-IIS/8.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcbWNocmlzdGVuc2VuXGRvY3VtZW50c1x2aXN1YWwgc3R1ZGlvIDIwMTNcUHJvamVjdHNcV2NmR2VuZXJpY3NcV2NmR2VuZXJpY3NcU2VydmljZTEuc3Zj?=
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Tue, 06 May 2014 18:47:29 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

What's the difference between how the WCF Test Client calls my web service and how Curl calls my web service?  Do I have the URL wrong?  Am I missing some HTTP headers?  Thanks!

**Update:**

I've tried the URL `http://localhost:64777/Service1.svc/TestStr` as well.  I've also tried *encoding* the file:

```
%3Cs%3AEnvelope%20xmlns%3As%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.xmlsoap.org%2Fsoap%2Fenvelope%2F%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cs%3AHeader%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CAction%20s%3AmustUnderstand%3D%221%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2Fws%2F2005%2F05%2Faddressing%2Fnone%22%3Ehttp%3A%2F%2Ftempuri.org%2FIService1%2FTestStr%3C%2FAction%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fs%3AHeader%3E%0A%20%20%3Cs%3ABody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTestStr%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ftempuri.org%2F%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fs%3ABody%3E%0A%3C%2Fs%3AEnvelope%3E
```

Both just result in *Bad Request*.

Comment: Have you considered adding a trace to get more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx?

Comment: It might be the url.  I think typically the method is part of the url: localhost\Service1\MethodToCall

Comment: Yea I've tried `http://localhost:64777/Service1.svc/TestStr` as well, same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Fiddler to capture the exact HTTP request. WCF tracing unfortunately does not capture the exact bytes sent over the wire. It reports a modified copy of the actual XML sent. Fiddler is not aware of web services so it does none of that.

Comment: I thought of that, but figured Fiddler wouldn't intercept WCF Test Client traffic.  Perhaps I'm wrong though.  I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you created a SOAP web service but I don't see any of the SOAP headers included in your example of the request data. In your web service code - add a line to capture the actual request being received by the service through the OperationContext object: `OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()`

You should be able to capture the data from the `RequestMessage` property, save that to a file, and then submit using CURL.

(You might have to strip out the `<Action>` elements as I think those are added by WCF and might cause problems if you try to submit a request with them included)